# A method for animation or library using React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, transition

I want help in creating this movie section for my website where I have this entrance animation but not fade in, and the smooth opening transition when clicking the card with image handling.

I tried using CSS transitions with width and height but all I can do is a traditional fade in and so much smooth transitions

I am not expert in animations and their naming that is why I am seeking assistance and I am using React as my Frontend.

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/112801165658901653/?mt=login

Comment: look at framer motion: https://www.framer.com/docs/ or more specifically the transitions section https://www.framer.com/docs/transition/

Answer (score 0):

Take in google libs node for parallax and slider.